# setOnClickPendingIntent in widget doesn't work

Tags: android, widget, click

I tried a lot to change my widget view's image when i click on it but it doesn't work. It's my code:

```
  public class myAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

        public static String ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH = "ActionReceiverRefresh";
         //...

    @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                int[] appWidgetIds) {

            final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

            // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, myAppWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
            }
```

And in onReceive i want to receive it when i click widget's view, but it doesn't work:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action)) {

            RemoteViews rmv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
                   //and this change doesn't work :(( \/
            rmv.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.button_power_on_small);
        }
    }
```

It's my android manifest receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="myAppWidgetProvider" android:exported="false" android:icon="@drawable/button_power_off">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        <action android:name="com.xxx.xxx.myAppWidgetProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH"/>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED"/>
</intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/widget_info_provider" />
</receiver>
```

I will be grateful if someone suggest me some solution.

Comment: try it with: rmv.setInt(R.id.imageView, "setImageResource",R.drawable.button_power_on_small);

Comment: It doesn't work, too, but i don't know whether onReceive method is called when i click the widget. I think that not, because methods in onReceive should works

Comment: a helpfull thing is to do logs on Your onReceive(). Then You will know if this is called and until which point the method works. Do first Log directly in onReceive after super(), the second should be inside Your if clause. If both are called You can be sure that there must be something wrong with Your remoteViews declaration. Example onReceive: Log.d("keyword","Action:onReceive");, Example if clause: Log.d("keyword","Action:if clause");

Comment: Oh thanks. It's great solution to check this. I place one Log with title "onReceive" after super method and one Log in body's condition if and it's strange becouse when i run app both of Logs are executed, but when i clicc widget's view when it is on home screen, then only first Log is show in LogCat.

Comment: could You make please another Log: Log.d("keyword","Acion:"+intent.getAction());, is this null?

Comment: And by the way i see that both of methods rmv.setInt(R.id.imageView, "setImageResource",R.drawable.button_power_on_small); and rmv.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.button_power_on_small); doesn't change my view's image

Comment: Yes of course, it's not null it's D/keyword(1918): Acion:ActionReceiverRefresh

Answer (score 2):

Change

`<action android:name="com.xxx.xxx.myAppWidgetProvider.ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH"/>`

to

`<action android:name="ActionReceiverRefresh"/>`

Your BroadcastReceiver is looking for the wrong action string. Remember that AndroidManifest is an XML file. You have to put the actual value of the String; pointing to a Java constant doesn't work.

Comment: Thank You for this good suggestion but i replace if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action)) with if (ACTION_WIDGET_REFRESH.equals(action)) and it's work properly too.

Comment: Ok, so like i sad methods which have to change view's image doesn't works. that methods: rmv.setInt(R.id.imageView, "setImageResource",R.drawable.button_power_on_small); and rmv.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.button_power_on_small);  Do someone know why?